# Finding the Time Since items interacted in SQL database

Tags: sql, time

I have a table such that I have

```
Item1  Item2  Timestamp  
A      B      2012-06-5 06:14:12   
B      A      2012-06-6 06:20:12   
C      A      2012-06-5 06:23:45   
A      B      2012-06-7 08:35:35   
C      A      2012-06-8 13:12:42  
B      C      2012-06-8 15:14:57
```

I want to append another column which we can call `time_since` that shows me the last time `Item1` and `Item2` interacted.

For example in Line Item 2 would have an extra row  with the number 6 in it. Since the two items interacted 6 minutes prior.

Comment: When you say "For example in Line Item 2 would have an extra row with the number 6 in it." do you actually mean "For example on line 2 this extra column should have the number 6 in it." If so, shouldn't it show a lot more than 6 minutes? It's a whole day AND 6 minutes after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think on the second row of your example data you meant to put June FIFTH (not 6th) in timestamp field? Only in that scenario would there be a difference of 6 minutes.

If that is true and you really do want the difference between in minutes you should be able to use the following:

**Fiddle Test:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aa157/4/0

```
select t1.item1,
       t1.item2,
       t1.timestamp,
       timestampdiff(minute, max(t2.timestamp), t1.timestamp) as time_diff
  from tbl t1
  left join tbl t2
    on t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp
   and ((t1.item1 = t2.item1 and t1.item2 = t2.item2) or
       (t1.item1 = t2.item2 and t1.item2 = t2.item1))
 group by t1.item1, t1.item2, t1.timestamp
 order by 3
```

(I changed the second row of your example data to be June 5th)